# C++ templating syntax - allocate type with pointer

Tags: c++, templates

How can I do memory allocation like this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
  T Generate()
  {
    return new T();    // Error
  }
};

A<B *> a;
B * pI = A.Generate();
```

Or can you only ever define something as:

```
A<B> a;
```

Comment: Consider reading the error message.

Comment: Also, you should write a.Generate() and not A.Generate()

Comment: For all those people bringing up the issue that I'm missing a 'public' modifier in the example code, yes you are right, but its after midnight here and your kinda missing the point.

Comment: @Nicholas you neglected telling us what your error is, so your problem quite possibly could have been the wrong access modifier.

Comment: @user2079303, sure, lets go with that.

Comment: @Nicholas please do, it would improve the usefulness of the question. Also, explaining your intention would be very advisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you wish to have specialization of A for pointer types. Try something like:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
  T *Generate()
  {
    printf("A\n");
    return new T;    // Error
  }
};

template <class T>
class A<T*> {
public:
  T *Generate() {
    printf("Specialization of A\n");
    return new T;
  }
};

class B {
};

int main() {
   A<B *> a;
   B * pI = a.Generate();
}
```

**Edit:**

To "override" only a part of the functionality:

```
template <class T>
class Generator
{
public:
  T *Generate()
  {
    printf("Generator\n");
    return new T;    // Error
  }
};

template <class T>
class Generator<T*> {
public:
  T *Generate() {
    printf("Specialization of Generator\n");
    return new T;
  }
};

template <class T>
class A: public Generator<T>
{
public:
  // does some other stuff
};
```

Comment: So define both and the compiler would automatically choose between the class implementations based on  whether I write A<B> or A<B *>?

Comment: @Nicholas Exactly, this is related to SFINAE - you may consider looking through this great feature of C++ language

Comment: Does class A<T*> need to be a 'complete' duplicate of class A? ie. containing every single member that class A does? or will just "class A<T*> {};" suffice?

Comment: Unfortunetly yes, but if you wish to have only functionality "overridden" you should consider using inheritance. I'll try to create a short example in edit...

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of issues with your code:

`A.Generate()` should be `a.Generate()` as `Generate` is a member function.

`new T()` returns `T*`, so your `Generate` function should look like:

```
T* Generate()
{
   return new T();
}
```

This should also be reflected in your usage:

```
A<B *> a;
B ** pI = a.Generate(); //generator for B* returns B**
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` will return a pointer so you need the signature

```
T* Generate()
{
    return new T();
}
```

This function must also be `public` if you'd like to call it outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do memory allocation like this

By fixing the syntax and semantic errors.

1. Return type of `Generate` is `T`, yet you return `T*`. You probably want to change the return type to `T*`. Accordingly, you must assign the returned type to a `T*` variable. Since your `T` is `B*`, that variable must have the type `B**`.
2. You try to call a non-static member of `A` without an instance. Call the member using the instance instead. Also, that member is private. Make it public.

When you've fixed the code, you'll see that it does memory allocation successfully.

> Or can you only ever define something as:

```
A<B> a;
```

No, there are many more ways to define something.